# how to change scrape_interval in prometheus operator dynamically for a specific target

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-operator

I am using prometheus operator to monitor my Kubernetes  cluster. I want to change the scrape_interval for some targets dynamically (increase and decrease it when needed at runtime).

Any suggestions to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look [here](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/user-guides/running-exporters.md#generic-servicemonitor-example) and let me know if it solves your problem. Notice field `interval` under .spec.endpoints[].

Comment: @HelloWorld thank you for your response. actually i want to find a method to change the scrape_interval in servicemonitor at runtime (i changed its value in servicemonitor.yaml but the prometheus configuration didn't change)

Comment: Prometheus-operator should reload promethus config automatically when changed so if it doesn't happen and you are sure this in not your fault I advise you to open issue on [promethus-operator github repo](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/issues)

Answer (score 1):

you can change that on the fly-
find servicemonitor ( on prometheus UI it is target ) as-
`kubectl get servicemonitor -n <NAMESPACE>`.

> `k get servicemonitor -n <NAMESPACE> <SERVICEMONITOR_NAME> -o yaml | sed 's/interval: [0-9][0-9]s/interval: 50s/' | kubectl replace -f -`

To reload automatically, prometheus operator has config-reloader, you can install that as a container alongside your prometheus.

Answer (score 1):

```
kubectl get secret -n monitoring prometheus-k8s -o json | jq  -r '.data."prometheus.yaml.gz"' | base64 -d | gzip -d
```

and then

```
kubectl edit secret -n monitoring prometheus-k8s
```